# resetting timer in impactjs

Tags: javascript, timer, impactjs

I am trying to reset my timer after a certain event is triggered. Currently I have my in-game timer which checks for that event every 4 seconds in my update as follows:

```
timer: new ig.Timer(),
update:function(){
           //console.log(this.timer.delta());
           if (this.timer.delta() >= 0) {
              this.performAchievementChecks();
              this.timer.set(4);
           }
 },

 performAchievementChecks:function(){
           if(tempArray.length >= 1 && this.Achievements[achID].status == this.storage.get(achKey)){
              this.performUpdate(achID);
           } 
 }

  performUpdate:function(achID){
           this.timer.set(0);
           this.updateAchievements(achID);
  }
```

So my function `performAchievementchecks()` is called every 4 seconds and within that time if its if statement goes `true` then I want to reset my timer back to 0 but it does not do it. Could someone please point out what is it that I am doing wrong? If so how do I reset my game timer from other different functions on occurrence of a certain event outside the `update()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what do you mean by **"reset my timer back to 0"**, if you only want the timer to reset, you don't have to do anything, as you have already set it `this.timer.set(4);`, the other option would be to disable it, and for this you can simply set the variable to null.

**Tips:**

1.You can create the timer directly with target:

```
timer: new ig.Timer(4)
```

And then use `this.timer.reset();` to restart the timer.

2.You can set the timer variable to null `this.timer = null;` if you want to disable it, and check if the variable is assigned in update funstion:

```
if (this.timer && this.timer.delta() >= 0) { ... }
```

PS: check the impact documentation on timers [here](http://impactjs.com/documentation/class-reference/timer)